# Parsing string pointer in C - Troubleshoot

Tags: c, string-parsing

**I am new to C**

I am trying to parse the string by "spaces" and "commas", string that `*ch` pointing to, but I am getting the first element only. Not sure what I am doing wrong, and I have wasted my whole day already on this, but still couldn't figure out.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
        char *ch = "This is a string, and fyunck you.";
        char cmd[100], *temp;
        int i = 0, size_ch = strlen(ch), count = 0;

        /* as strtok only support string array */
        for (i = 0; i < size_ch; i++){
                if (ch[i] != ','){
                        cmd[count] = ch[i];
                        count++;
                }
        }
        cmd[count] = '\0';
        printf("cmd: %s\n", cmd);

        ch = strtok(cmd, " ");
        printf("ch: %s\n", ch);

        while ( (ch = strtok(NULL, " ")) != NULL)
                printf("%s\n", cmd);
}
```

> **Output**
>
> cmd: This is a string and fyunck you
>
> ch: This
>
> This
>
> This
>
> This
>
> This
>
> This
>
> This

whereas, the output should be

> **Desire Output**
>
> cmd: This is a string and fyunck you
>
> ch: This
>
> is
>
> a
>
> string
>
> and
>
> fyunck
>
> you

**Note:** I am not allowed to use external libraries.

**P.S** I am trying to replicate this code, [Code](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/efeciftci/9120921/raw/e85635e498e554785afaad04cd4747a840a2d8ce/strtok_example.c)

Comment: The last line is printing `cmd`, but I think you want to print `ch`. You may also want to look at `strsep(3)`, which is a bit easier to work with and supports multiple delimiters.

Comment: In the last loop, `printf("%s\n", cmd);` should be `printf("%s\n", ch);`

Comment: LOL, it worked.... Can't believe I have spent my whole day on this silly mistake.

Comment: @bnaecker, since you are the first to point out. Please add that as your answer, and I will mark you correct. Thank you btw :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're just printing the wrong variable in the last line.

Change

```
printf("%s\n", cmd);
```

to

```
printf("%s\n", ch);
```

and it should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Note this:

```
while ((ch = strtok(NULL, " ")) != NULL)
    printf("%s\n", cmd);
```

You are updating `ch`, and outputting `cmd`, which remains unchanged.

To fix this, simply change it to:

```
while ((ch = strtok(NULL, " ")) != NULL)
    printf("%s\n", ch);
```